# Como criar uma função SQL que chama um script em python?

Tags: php, sql, python, banco-de-dados, .exe

Eu preciso criar um software que a cada inserção em uma tabela uma script em python detecte que houve mudança nessa tabela e execute determinados comando.
Eu já fiz uma implementação que fica toda hora testando se houve mudança na tabela, porém isso me obriga a fazer um `while True`que roda em segundo plano eternamente. Fiz dessa forma:

```
import urllib
import urllib2
import webbrowser
import popular3
while True:


    tabela    = popular3.Banco()
    if (tabela.existeMudancaNaTabela()):
        #Faz alguns comandos
        pass




    print "Esperando Mudança no Banco..."
```

Eu preciso criar uma **função no próprio SQL**  que detecte que houve uma inserção de dados em uma tabela e, logo apos, chame a execução de um sricpt .py ou um .exe ou qualquer outro. Será que isso é possível?

Comment: Pesquise sobre trigger para banco de dados, pode te ajudar

Comment: Qual banco de dados você está utilizando?

Comment: Utilizo o MySQL.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html

Comment: É possível fazer um trigger chamar um script python externo? Pelo o que eu pesquisei ele só faz ações internas com comando sql.

Comment: provavelmente não: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1467369/invoking-a-php-script-from-a-mysql-trigger

Comment: Vlw, acho que dá pra fazer com UDF library.

Comment: Se o seu servidor for Linux, você pode criar um Cron para executar seus scripts. No windows também tem algo parecido, é o Agendador de Tarefas, basta configura-lo e ele executa alguma coisa de tempo em tempo.

Comment: Mude para o PostgreSQL e utilize a PL/Python para desenvolver a função trigger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Se o seu banco for PostgreSQL

você pode colocar uma função em PL/Python direto dentro do banco - a documentação está aqui:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/plpython.html

Eu não sei se o Python dentro do postgresql vai ter limitações (como acesso ao filesystem, importar módulos terceiros que não tenham a ver com o postgres, etc...) mas provavelmente não tem limitações: é muito difícil criar limitações efetivas desse tipo em Python - e para ter uma "aparência" de segurança, é melhor documentar que funções em Python podem fazer tudo, e aumentar o leque de escolhas.

## Se o sistema que insere no banco for em Python

Isso nos trás para outra coisa: se o sistema que estiver *inserindo* no banco de dados for em Python, então os melhores ORM de Python (como o SQLALchemy) tem um sistema de eventos - você colcoaria seu código Python como um handler para evento do SQLAlchemy.

## Se não for nem PostgreSQL, nem inserção por Python:

Você vai precisar enviar um sinal pra fora do banco de alguma forma  a partir de scripts usados como trigger dentro do banco em outras linguagens. Isso exigiria bastante configuração específica, e poderia ser problemático quando o banco estiver numa máquina separada do seu script Python (vamos supor que você ponha um trigger que faça uma chamada de socket, que ative o seu script de Python - quando estiver em produção e a rede ára chegar até o banco configurada de forma segura, seria uma dor de cabeça ter essa chamada do banco de volta para o seu servidor onde está o script Python).

Então, a idéia de ter um script Python que olha o banco ativamente a cada intervalo curto de tempo não é ruim não.  O que você pode fazer, em vez de fazer uma query longa que olha a tabela inteira é:

- criar uma tabela simples, só para dizer se houve mudança ou não - 
  poderia ser uma tabela com uma únic alinha e uma única coluna o tipo "bool(alterado)"
- Colocar um trigger no banco para setar um "alterado=true" nessa tabela cada vez que uma das mudanças que te interessam acontecer.
- Por o seu script olhando o banco a cada 1 ou 2 segundos, checando essa tabela simples  - e só fazer queries mais extensas se houve alteração